# Should I install self-leveling material over or under backer board?

Tags: bathroom, flooring

Redoing a master bath. Right now it has OSB Subfloor down. The floor varies in how level it is some parts are 1/4" to 3/4" off.

I was planning on putting down 1/4" HardieBacker board then pouring self-leveling above this so the tile floor is level.

Is this the correct process? Should I look into a different solution to get the floor level?

Comment: Is the floor wavely or a flat slope?  Floor finish covering don't care about flat slopes, you might if it is too much.   Dips, ridges, waves do need leveling.  Would place levelling stuff before more flooring, imagine 1/4 inch will not like dips.

Comment: The floor is wavy so up and down in different spots. So you suggest putting leveling then backer board? Because to me that doesn't make sense bc when you put a screw to hold the backer it would break the self leveler.

Comment: Is the room such that you can lift the subfloor and repair the framing? That's the right fix, IMO.

Comment: Have not used backer boards, but doubt they like waves that much either.  Wait till more experience people join in.

Comment: Cement board is quite flexible. It would handle some curves fine, assuming it's screwed down well. I just don't like self-leveler in general. It's not as easy as folks tend to think, and it's chalky and weak (especially if over-watered).

Comment: Tim, my primary concern is putting wet stuff down on OSB. You'd want to put down poly first. I don't consider running screws through the leveler to be a problem, and I'd rather bond tile directly to backer board, but as I said I'd rather avoid this situation altogether. Please update your post to provide more context, and add photos if possible.

Comment: @Isherwood thats a good idea for sistering the joists to get them level and then just installing new subfloor on top then the self leveling wouldn't be needed.

Comment: If you need to attach the backer board through the SLC, then use long enough screws to go all the way through the subfloor and into the joists. That way, even if the SLC cracks a little, the screws still have solid purchase in the joists. You'd probably want to do that anyway. I'd agree with @isherwood that leveling the joists would be the _best_ option and think he should write that up as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You want your floor flat - levelness doesn't matter too much.

I assume you have a transition in the doorway to handle any changes in room to room level.

The professional answer to this question is to flood the entire bathroom with enough SLC that it slightly covers the high portion of the floor.  This is the most materially expensive option but the easiest, least labor intensive, most fool proof and highest profit (for a contractor).  You'd need to use the primer for the SLC you choose.

An option, as isherwood points out, is to pull the subfloor and sister the joists and get the joists perfect then re-install the osb.  If your subfloor has been glued with construction adhesive and is nailed down and is under your walls, I recommend against this approach in a small room.

The more labor intensive hybrid approach is to find the high spots, find the low spots and do a combination of filling and sanding.  I suppose you could also supplement this and remove a high area and shave down the joist and re-install some osb instead.  It depends on a few things.

How big is the bathroom?

how thick is your osb?

are your joists i-joists or standard spf?  or do you have psl lvl etc.

are you planning on LFT / what size are your floor tiles?

why are you planning on 1/4" backerboard over the osb?

I've done 3/8" plywood on top of osb and then added two lifts of SLC (with primer in between).  You can drill through SLC without cracking it.  Are you doing a crack isolation membrane in between your tile and your subfloor?

Answer (score 1):

Pouring self leveling over OSB is a bit risky, you'd have to be really sure there are no holes or cracks anywhere otherwise it will leak, which could make low spots and a huge mess on the floor below...

Anyway. If the self-levelling is done properly it will be flat and ready to tile without using backer board. However it is not waterproof, so it needs an extra waterproofing step, and when used on wood it tends to end up cracking under the tiles if it's too thin, which you get to notice later when the tiles start to pop off. So I would rate the self-levelling solution with a "meh".

If possible I would remove the OSB and put shims on the joists to make everything flat and level, then put the OSB back. That's the correct solution really, but it's only possible if the walls don't sit on top of the OSB.

Otherwise I'd apply primer on the OSB, then either apply self-leveling or level it with thinset. That's a paste, so it doesn't leak, and it's not difficult to make it flat with a straightedge. Then once it's flat enough, I'd apply more thinset and lay the backer board on it as if it was tile.

If there is a bedroom below the bathroom, you might also consider soundproofing the floor, that requires a soundproofing layer (about 5mm thick wood fiber panels) and another layer of OSB or thicker backer board on top.